# Split phrase by word(s) with delimiters, not able to use a string variable

Tags: xparse

**The Objective**: Send a string variable which contains a phrase containing multiple words delimited with commas or semicolon using the xparse functions \SplitList and \ProcessList.

**The Problem** The function does either not recognize the string or does not split the prhase.  See example where I am able to split the phrase manually entered as parameter of the function

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\isplit}{>{\SplitList{,}} m}{\ProcessList{#1}
\i@split}
\NewDocumentCommand{\i@split}{>{\SplitList{;}}m}{\ProcessList{#1}\i@paint}
\NewDocumentCommand{\i@paint}{m}{
{\fbox{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\newtoks\myvar  % ** Best way to keep string variable values hidden? 
\newcommand{\anotherstring}{}   % ** Shows value upon assigment.  
                                % ** Not good
\begin{document}

\myvar{doc begins}%
% new command variable; not preferred I want to hide the assigned string
\anotherstring{do not want; to show, the string value; yet}
\newline%
\the\myvar%     % ** An example to show how to retrieve the value of hpvar
\newline%
\newline%
\newline%
this is how it should be: \isplit{this,sample;works!}%
\newline%
oops! \isplit{\anotherstring}
\newline%
\myvar{this,sample;hpvar does not work}%
myvar: \isplit{\the\myvar}%
\end{document}
```

Ouput:
[image: To Split or not to split, that is the question]

Answer (score 4):

This is all "out of the box" with the `listofitems` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\def\anotherstring{do not want; to show, the string value; yet}

\setsepchar{,||;}

\readlist*\mylist{this,sample;works!}
\showitems\mylist

\readlist*\mylist{\anotherstring}
\showitems\mylist

The list has \mylistlen{} items.

Item 4 of the list is ``\mylist[4]''

\readlist*\mylist{this,sample;hpvar does not work}
\showitems\mylist
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `\SplitList` does not expand the argument, using another `wrapper` command will expand the argument first, then feed it into `\isplit` which in turn uses `\i@split` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\isplit}{m}{\expandafter\@@isplit\expandafter{#1}}


\NewDocumentCommand{\@@isplit}{>{\SplitList{,}} m}{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\i@split}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\i@split}{>{\SplitList{;}}m}{\ProcessList{#1}\i@paint}
\NewDocumentCommand{\i@paint}{m}{%
{\fbox{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\newtoks\myvar  % ** Best way to keep string variable values hidden? 
\newcommand{\anotherstring}{}   % ** Shows value upon assigment.  
                                % ** Not good
\begin{document}

\myvar={doc begins}%
% new command variable; not preferred I want to hide the assigned string
\renewcommand{\anotherstring}{do not want; to show, the string value; yet}

\the\myvar%     % ** An example to show how to retrieve the value of hpvar

this is how it should be: \isplit{this,sample;works!}%

oops! \isplit{\anotherstring}

\myvar{this,sample;hpvar does not work}%
\the\myvar

myvar: \isplit{\the\myvar}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the usage for this would be; nonetheless you're misusing `xparse`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for the example

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\isplit}{smO{\fbox}}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \hpcolos_isplit:VN #2 #3 }
   { \hpcolos_isplit:nN { #2 } #3 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \hpcolos_isplit:nN
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__hpcolos_isplit_input_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__hpcolos_isplit_input_tl { ; } { , }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__hpcolos_isplit_input_seq { , } \l__hpcolos_isplit_input_tl
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__hpcolos_isplit_input_seq #2
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hpcolos_isplit:nN { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\coloredbox}[1]{\colorbox{green}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mystring}{do not want; to show, the string value; yet}

\isplit{do not want; to show, the string value; yet}

\isplit*{\mystring}

\isplit{do not want; to show, the string value; yet}[\coloredbox]

\isplit*{\mystring}[\coloredbox]

\end{document}
```

The string is normalized to have comma separators, then split and each item is passed to the function in the optional argument, default `\fbox`.

Something more can be done, but your question is too generic for making guesses.

[image]

Comment: I put a simple code as always is requested in this forum.  The real application in my case is to use "keywords" separated by commas or semicolon stored in a key using xkeyval  with the package songs for a songbook of about 300 songs and growing, where you could add custom keys to each song.  The keywords stored in a key could be "entrance; wedding; communion; advent, etc" The keywords obtained from that key for each song will be split-ted to automate index entries (e.g. index{\keysplitted!\songtitle}), a function not provided by the songs package.  Very useful answers so far.  Thanks